# Detect version 1 or version 2 Pi

Tags: i2c

I'm writing a small application that could run on version one Pi ( mine ) or a version two ( co-workers ) that uses the I2C bus.

Since the I2C bus is different depending on the version, I was wondering how I programmatically detect which is which so neither of us have to mess with changing any settings when we

Comment: It seems like your question was cut off halfway. I recommend editing this post.

Comment: It seems that the bus is selected through the `/etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf` file. I assume that you could check which one was commented out?

Answer (score 1):

Gordon Henderson's [wiringPi](https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/) project includes a function `piBoardRev` which does what you want; looking at the code, it checks `/proc/cpuinfo` for a "Revision" line and works on that, so you might find it easier to do the same yourself.

There's a [discussion on the Raspberry Pi Forum](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=23989).